# how to restrict a method to n concurrent calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, concurrency

I have an integration service which runs a calculation heavy, data bound process. I want to make sure that there are never more than say, n = 5, (but n will be configurable, changeable at runtime) of these processes running at the same. The idea is to throttle the load on the server to a safe level. The amount of data processed by the method is limited by batching, so I don't need to worry about 1 process representing a much bigger load than another.

The processing method is called by another process, where requests to run payroll are held on a queue, and I can insert some logic at that point to determine whether to process this request now, or leave it on the queue.

So i want a seperate method on the same service as the processing method, which can tell me if the server can accept another call to the processing method. It's going to ask, "how many payroll runs are going on? is that less than n?" What's a neat way of achieving this?

-----------edit------------

I think I need to make it clear, the process that decides whether to take the request off the queue this is seperated from the service that processes the payroll data by a WCF boundary. Stopping a thread on the payroll processing process isn't going to prevent more requests coming in

Comment: I'm not familiar with threaded programming (hence a comment), but it sounds to me like this is a perfect job for a threadpool.

Comment: You may just be able to use a Semaphore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might want a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), where each item in the collection represents one of the concurrent calls.

Also see [IProducerConsumerCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx).

If you were just using threads, I'd suggest you look at the methods for limiting thread concurrency (e.g. the [TaskScheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel.aspx) property, and [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx).).

Also see [ParallelEnumerable.WithDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx)

Comment: This is limiting access from the caller side, not the callee side.  That's not always possible, and not what the OP is asking.  What if this is inside of an ASP application and he doesn't want too many requests pinging this outside resource at once.  You wouldn't want to limit the thread pool to a small number of threads as it would slow down all of the rest of the processing on the site, you just want to limit access to this one resource.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I DO want to block access from the caller side. If I block on the callee side requests are still going to be flying at my service when it's not ready for them.

Comment: I think this was most suitable for what I wanted, although I later realised that I could track how much work was happening on the caller side without having to interrogate the workers

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Semaphore` to do this.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    public Foo(int numConcurrentCalls)
    {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(numConcurrentCalls, numConcurrentCalls);
    }

    public bool isReady()
    {
        return semaphore.WaitOne(0);
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        try
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();//it will only get past this line if there are less than 
            //"numConcurrentCalls" threads in this method currently.
            //do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonnyCundall Added, but keep in mind that the open slots may all be filled between the time you call `IsReady` and then when you call the `Bar`.  `Bar` will actually just block and wait until there are less than the required other threads in the method, so you shouldn't need an `IsReady` method in the first place.  Note that `WaitOne` has a number of other overloads.  You can give it a timeout, for example, if you don't want to block for more than a set period of time.

Comment: see edit - It looks like I've given you the impression that the caller and callee are both on the same machine, sorry about that. I need to block on the caller side because I don't want blocked service calls to build up.

Comment: @JonnyCundall Is there only one caller, or are there many callers?  If there is one, then just use the semaphore to limit the calls on that side.  If there are many, then it's a particularly hard problem.  The call to ask if there is a place needs to reserve a spot, but you need to wait for a full round trip across the server before it can use it, so you'll end up with a *lot* of lost throughput.  Why can't lots of callers just call the method and block until there are few enough to let another one start the work?

Comment: There will be more than on caller on production I think as there's lots of redundancy. At peak times there could be a lot more demand than the server can process. So requests could be queuing up for hours. I'd rather they were queueing up in the caller's queue than either on the WCF boundary, or as blocked threads - I don't know how reliable either of those would be.

Comment: I think it should be "new Semaphore(numConcurrentCalls, numConcurrentCalls)" - if the initial count is zero, WaitOne() will block indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

Review the [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) pattern.  This is what you're describing.  While not strictly required by the pattern, you can expose the number of objects currently in the pool, the maximum (configured) number, the high-watermark, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ThreadTest()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int> q = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    int MaxCount = 5;
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        q.Enqueue(r.Next(100000, 200000));
    }

    ThreadStart proc = null;
    proc = () =>
    {
        int read = 0;
        if (q.TryDequeue(out read))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{1:HH:mm:ss}.{1:fff}] starting: {0}... @Thread {2}", read, DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(100, 1000));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{1:HH:mm:ss}.{1:fff}] {0} ended! @Thread {2}", read, DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            proc();
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i <= MaxCount; i++)
    {
        new Thread(proc).Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict anything from the callee side, it does it from the caller side by only creating a limited number of threads.  That's not what the question asks.  He wants the callee to limit access assuming more threads than are desirable are trying to access the method.

Comment: I guess you dont get the idea. Instead of performing calls you fill a collection with the data you want to process. You can configure the amount of threads anywhere in the code.